# Outlook Showing in Process even after closing - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms, outlook

I am writing a code in WPF such that I will get a trigger when ever outlook opens

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application _outlook;
 OutlookWatcher OutlookWatcher = null;
 internal void GetOutlookApp()
 {
     try
     {
         Process[] processlist = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
         if (processlist.Count() > 0)
         {
             if (_outlook == null)
             {
                 var outlook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
                 _outlook = outlook;
                 if (OutlookWatcher != null)
                 {
                     OutlookWatcher.Dispose();
                 }
                 OutlookWatcher = new OutlookWatcher(_outlook);
                 OutlookWatcher.MailOpened += OutlookWatcher_MailOpened;
                 OutlookWatcher.MailClosed += OutlookWatcher_MailClosed;
                 CheckOutlookProcess();
                 outlook = null;
             }
             else
             {
                 OutlookWatcher.CheckExplorers();
             }
         }
         else if (processlist.Count() == 0 && _outlook != null)
         {
             if (OutlookWatcher != null)
             {
                 OutlookWatcher.Dispose();
             }
             OutlookWatcher = null;
             _outlook = null;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         if (OutlookWatcher != null)
         {
             OutlookWatcher.Dispose();
         }
         OutlookWatcher = null;
         _outlook = null;
     }
 }
```

Works great for the first time when I open outlook, but the code continue to execute even after outlook is closed .

I also checked the background process there is no outlook process running.
Help appreciated :) .

Comment: Messageboxes are meant to be closed by clicking OK? Is your problem that the MessageBox reopens then show the surrounding code. Or do you expect  that the MessageBox magically closes itself? Then write code that supervises that Outlook is running or not regularly and hide the MessageBox in case by code. (Presumably you need then a simple own Dialog instead of a MessageBox)

Comment: Or is your problem that Outlook is still running in the background? That then dependent on settings of and version of Outlook you use. Closing a Window is not the same then closing a process.

Comment: @Ralf  Message box is not the problem, its just for an example, Whenever I am checking that the outlook process  is running the code gets executed for first time, but when I close outlook the code executes again .

Comment: Are you using the interop libraries to open Outlook in the first place?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes

Comment: Why are you using `GetProcessesByName` then? The interop code you used is most likely keeping Outlook up, especially if you used CreateObject to *start* Outlook instead of GetObject to attach to a running version. How did you close Outlook? And what code executes again? The code you posted doesn't trigger anything, it checks whether a process exists in a tight loop. If you don't close it properly, it will remain active

Comment: @raw_hitt - Are you calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` ***on every single reference*** you make to a COM object after you've finished with them? And that includes each level of nested references.

Comment: Post the interop code you use to create, use and close Outlook. That's where the problem is

Comment: @Enigmativity yes I am calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used GetProcessesByName just to add a check if outlook is in the process else it is throwing an exception when using Marshal.GetActiveObject

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interop code posted

Comment: Now we just need to guess what OutlookWatcher does and if it was correctly implemented? Come on.

Comment: Launching a copy of outlook from a webform/web page is really not going to work well

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it is not webform

Comment: OK, then why is this tagged as asp.net then, which of course means web based,  right?

Comment: `GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")` connects to an already active Outlook instance, eg the current user's Outlook instance Releasing the reference doesn't close the application - users would be very angry if that happened. You *could* call `Quit` on the reference but as I said, users wouldn't like that

Comment: What's the *actual* question? Are you getting a message that *Outlook* is busy? Such a message means that Outlook is still controlled by another process. Your current code never disposes `_outlook`, leaving the connection active until the garbage collector runs. You need to use `Dispose` at the very least *and* use `ReleaseComObject` on `_outlook`. COM uses reference counting, not garbage collection. Each time you take a reference to a COM object the reference counter is increased by 1. You need to release that object explicitly to reduce the counter to 0 to finally release the object.

Comment: A COM server (in this case Outlook) will remain in memory as long as *any* of its objects are still active. That's why Enigmativity asked if you call `ReleaseComObject` on every reference. `_outlook` is certainly not released. `OutlookWatcher` may be creating other references too, to track what the user does. Those need to be released too.

Comment: @raw_hitt - You need to show us all of the code you have written that in any way interacts with any COM object. You don't show us where you are releasing the objects and that it almost 100% the cause of your issue. Show us the full code please.